# Java Netbeans: Method return value should be checked with semicolon

Tags: java, netbeans

I am a beginner Java programmer and using Netbeans IDE.

Here is my code:

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name;
    System.out.println("Hello, what is your name?");
    name = user_input.next();

    System.out.println("");

    String name_answer;
    System.out.println("Your name is " + name + ". Is this correct? (yes/no)");
    name_answer = user_input.next();

    System.out.println("");

    if (name_answer.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Thank you, " + name + ". Please proceed to the next question.");
    } else if (name_answer.equals("no")) {
        System.out.println("Please reinput your name correctly.");
        for (name_answer.equals("no")) {
            String name_again;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("What is your correct name?");
            name_again = user_input.next();

            System.out.println("");

            System.out.println("Your name is " + name_again + ". Is this correct? (yes/no)");
            name_answer = user_input.next();        
        }
    }
```

At the line of the for loop [   for(name_answer.equals("no"))   ], it is giving me this problem:

```
   ';' expected

    Should check the method return value
```

I can't find any solutions, please help!

Also, I am trying to create the loop that whenever the user answers "no" to the question "Is this correct (yes/no)", it loops to the "What is your correct name?". Is this how the loop will turn out, if not, how can i fix it?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Check this ..[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)  this would help

Comment: do you want to use `while` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loop takes 3 parameters:
The syntax of a for loop is −

```
for(initialization; Boolean_expression; update) {
   // Statements
}

for (name_answer.equals("no"))
```

Change it to:

```
for (;name_answer.equals("no");)
```

But as other people suggested, using `while` is a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> for (name_answer.equals("no")) {
>   above syntax is wrong .

for loop come in two flavours.

1. ```
   for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
   ```

   //
           }
2. for(int i : intArray){ 
   //

   }

Answer (score 0):

I can see what you are trying to accomplish, but you need to understand how a `for` loop works. Rather than just giving you the answer I suggest reading the Oracle documentation regarding the `for` statement: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the methods before you finish initializing the variables you're calling.
You have used the incorrect for loop

example

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
System.out.println(i)
}
```

But in your case, you have used

```
for (name_answer.equals("no")) {
        String name_again;
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("What is your correct name?");
        name_again = user_input.next();

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Your name is " + name_again + ". Is this correct? (yes/no)");
        name_answer = user_input.next();        
    }
```